# How can I produce TeX Gyre Pagella smallcaps using xelatex?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, small-caps

Here's my input file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{TeXGyrePagella}

\begin{document}
abcde ABCDE

{\scshape abcde ABCDE}

\textsc{abcde ABCDE}
\end{document}
```

Here's the xelatex rendering:

[image]

As best I can understand from the documentation, the two small capitals commands should work because `otfinfo` shows them as being a feature of the TeX Gyre Pagella font:

```
$ otfinfo -f /usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf
...
smcp    Small Capitals
...
```

System details: Ubuntu 11.04, texlive-xetex version is 2009-11.

Here's the output of `fc-cache | grep Pagella`. It seems to suggest that the string `TeXGyrePagella` is correct:

```
$ fc-list | grep Pagella
TeXGyrePagella:style=BoldItalic
TeXGyrePagella:style=Regular
TeXGyrePagella:style=Bold
TeXGyrePagella:style=Italic
```

If I change the `\setmainfont` command to: `\fontspec[Mapping=tex-text,Path=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/]{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}`,
I get this error output:

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm texgyrepagella-regular
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for texgyrepagella-regular.
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input texgyrepagella-regular
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf texgyrepagella-regular
! I can't find file `texgyrepagella-regular'.
<*> ...; nonstopmode; input texgyrepagella-regular

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...; nonstopmode; input texgyrepagella-regular

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: texgyrepagella-regular.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input texgyrepagella-regular' failed to make texgyrepagella-regular.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font \zf@basefont=texgyrepagella-regular.otf at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (
TFM) file or installed font not found.
\zf@fontspec ...ntname \zf@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                              \unless \ifzf@icu \zf@set@...
l.3 ...blic/tex-gyre/]{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}
```

The file `/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyrepagella-regular.otf` definitely exists on my system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
```

with the spaces in the OTF font family name I get:

[image]

Searching for the family names:

```
voss@shania:~> fc-list | grep Pagella
TeX Gyre Pagella:style=Italic
TeX Gyre Pagella:style=Bold Italic
TeX Gyre Pagella:style=Regular
TeX Gyre Pagella:style=Bold
voss@shania:~>
```

my fontspec versions:

```
*File List*
fontspec.sty 2011/02/26 v2.1f Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX
fontspec-patches.sty 2011/02/26 v2.1f Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/Lu
aLaTeX
xunicode.sty 2010/11/06 v0.96 provides access to latin accents and many othe
r characters in Unicode lower plane
fontspec.cfg
```

Comment: I get an error: "(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg))kpathsea: Invalid fontname `TeX Gyre Pagella', contains ' '"

Comment: then run `fc-list | grep Pagella` to get the correct family name. See edited answer

Comment: I've put my output in the original question: "TeXGyrePagella" still seems to be right.

Comment: It looks odd that your fontspec is in tex/xelatex/ I would expect in tex/latex/. Also it shouldn't complain about spaces in the name. Are you sure that you have an up-to-date fontspec?

Comment: ok, then try: `\fontspec[Mapping=tex-text,Path=/usr/share/texmf/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/]{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}` instead of `\setmainfont`.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer: I'm using the fontspec as provided by Ubuntu's texlive-xetex package: like many Linux users I like to use the distribution's software packages rather than direct installs.

Comment: XeTeX needs the filename of the font if it is installed in the TeX tree

Comment: @puzzlement Unfortunately, the Linux distributions all seem to include rather old versions of TeX Live. TeX Live 2010 will be superseded by TeX Live 2011 in a week or so, and you are still using TeX Live 2009! I'm afraid that the version of `fontspec` (and possibly XeTeX) you have are too old.

Comment: Herbert: the output from your command is shown in the OP. However given Joseph's comment I think I will revert to using pdflatex, I have a very strong preference against needing to hand install software on the several different desktop machines I need to run LaTeX on.

Comment: @puzzlement: all Linux distributions are unable to handle a TeX distribution. It is too big to split into several packages which can then easily be updated. The reason why an installation of texlive from http://tug.org/texlive really makes sense.

Comment: @puzzlement: Getting back to pdflatex will help you with this problem. But it will not solve the problem that a lot of files/packages in your TeX is outdated. If you need packages like hyperref, tikz/pgf, biblatex, siunitx, expl3 ... which have been updated a lot in the last two years you will run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

The OTF name for the font is "TeX Gyre Pagella".  The PostScript name is "TeXGyrePagella".  If you only see the PostScript name, it means xelatex can't find the OTF file.  As other examples discuss, this is a bug of the packaging, either TeX Live or Debian.  Some PostScript fonts are installed in system folders, but not the small caps.  The workaround is to copy the .otf file (that you found) into "~/.fonts/".