# How can I produce TeX Gyre Pagella smallcaps using LuaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, small-caps

This is the same basic question as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/351092/11376) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22934/11376) but for LuaLaTeX. I don't know if I'm missing something but the following does not work for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}
\noindent
123456789ABCDEF

\noindent
\textsc{123456789ABCDEF}
\end{document}
```

The OldStyle numerals come through fine but I cannot get small caps to work no matter what I do. I do not see any warnings or errors in the output when I run `lualatex test.tex`, and the output contains:

```
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyrepagel
la-regular.otf>
```

So I think it's loading the font correctly.

What gives?

Edit: Note, this isn't just about TeX Gyre Pagella. I can reproduce the same results with e.g., Minion Pro, which I have been able to use with small caps in other programs. I just included TeX Gyre Pagella here because it makes the reproducer easier to distribute.

Comment: Try `\textsc{abcdef}`: uppercase in small caps is the same as uppercase in the normal shape.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the meaning of “small caps”: it only has effects on *lowercase* letters.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{TeX Gyre Pagella}

\begin{document}
\noindent
123456789ABCDEFabcdef

\noindent
\textsc{123456789ABCDEFabcdef}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am officially an idiot. Thank you.

Comment: @ElliottSlaughter Oh, don't worry! Misunderstandings happen! :-)